# Is there a limit on the number of stateless services in one service fabric application

Tags: asp.net, azure, memory-management, azure-service-fabric

I have to create 28 stateless services under one service fabric application. The role of each state less service is just to listen to the service bus queue, retrieve the messages and post them to a Rest endpoint. Is there a hard limit on how many stateless services that can be created on a single azure service fabric application? Do we run into any memory issues by having numerous stateless services?

EDIT : We looked on the server itself and saw that each app takes up about 250 MB mem.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing comes for free. Each stateless service will use some memory, also of course largely depending on what it is doing. There is no hard limit but the size of the underlying machine and possibly the scale of the cluster do define the limits. What is the instance count of each service anyway?